# How can I ensure that files without extensions are installed using Module::Build?

Tags: perl, module-build

I am converting an inherited software collection to a [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Module%3a%3aBuild) based distribution.

The `lib` directories contain, in addition to the `.pm` files, certain external files needed by the modules. It is easy to ensure that the ones that have extensions are copied along with the `.pm` files by using `Module::Build`'s `add_build_element` method.

But I am confused about how to deal with files that have no extensions. How can I make sure those files are also copied alongside the `.pm` files during installation? Is there a way to tell `Module::Build` to copy *everything* under `lib`?

Comment: +1 for being the 10k Perl question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Build.PL**

```
use lib 'inc';
use Local::Module::Build::Extensionless;

my $build = Local::Module::Build::Extensionless->new(
    module_name => 'Foo::Bar',
    license     => 'restricted',
);
$build->add_build_element('lib');
$build->create_build_script;
```

**inc/Local/Module/Build/Extensionless.pm**

```
package Local::Module::Build::Extensionless;
use parent 'Module::Build';
use File::Next qw();

sub process_lib_files {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $files;

    {
        my $iter = File::Next::files('lib');
        while (defined(my $file = $iter->())) {
            $files->{$file} = $file;
        }
    }

    # following piece from Module::Build::Base::process_files_by_extension
    while (my ($file, $dest) = each %$files) {
        $self->copy_if_modified(from => $file, to => File::Spec->catfile($self->blib, $dest));
    }
};
1;
```

But why so complicated? You really want [share_dir](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aAPI#share_dir).

Answer (score 3):

If these are module specific data files; there's a somewhat obscure convention that data owned by lib/Acme/Foo/Bar.pm is usually placed in lib/auto/Acme/Foo/Bar/.

Most packers including Module::Build should respect this convention and automatically treat this as a "data payload" and package it along with the module files.

There's some helper modules including [File::ShareDir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aShareDir) that can help you locate the data at runtime.

```
use File::ShareDir;
my $data_dir = File::ShareDir::module_dir('Acme::Foo::Bar');
```

Just one possible approach. I'm hoping it might fit your detailed requirements.

Comment: `File::ShareDir` is a fine solution in other circumstances, but it is not suitable in my case. Thank you.

Comment: Using `File::ShareDir` is the right answer. It's a pity Sinan didn't elaborate as to why he thought it was unsuitable for his needs.